# Implementing different online payment options on different products in Magento

Tags: magento, online-store

In Magento, I need to implement different checkout options for different product types. Is this possible?

To clarify, I have one set of products that can be paid by credit card *or* by cash on delivery, and a different set of products that should only be paid by credit card.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in standard Magento, you need to make an own extension for that.

[N98_CheckoutFilters](https://github.com/netz98/N98_CheckoutFilters) could be a starting point on how to filter out payment methods in the checkout.